# In Studio Flow, how to know if a Gather-Input-On-Call widget ends with no input or time out

Tags: twilio

I have a Gather-Input-On-Call widget that stops gathering on key press #. I want to know if this widget times out or user pressed # only. Both of them are treated as NoInput now. How to distinguish between them?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a distinction since a `#` without any input is considered No Input (as the # is not submitted).

What are you trying to achieve that you need to determine the difference? It sounds like you are overloading the role of `#`?

Comment: Hi Alan! I want to let the user input an id (number) if he has one, or he can simply press # if he hasn’t one. If the widget timed out, I want to ask again instead of treating it as he hasn’t an id. Now I let user input 0# if he hasn’t an id but I think pressing just # is more user-friendly.